# I have problem with create .mdf file in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When i trying to create. Mdf file in App_Data folder in visual studio 2010 I see this message. 
"Failed to generate user instance of SQL Server due to an error when starting the process for an instance of the user. The connection will be closed." 
I can to create the database other ways. (In visual studio -> Tools-> Connect to the database and SQL Manager). SQL Server is installed automatically studio.

How can I solve this problem? 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer to your question, however I think it is very important you read [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684.aspx) first before attempting any further resolutions to your problem.